# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Item amount is invalid (#10630: Item amount is invalid)

Tags: paypal, magento-1.9

When i generate invoice selecting option "online capture" option from magento admin then i am getting error please read below:

"PayPal gateway has rejected request. Item amount is invalid (#10630: Item amount is invalid)."

Order detail is

Subtotal    =                      $349.00

You Redeemed(0 Reward points ($0.00))= $0.00

Grand Total = $349.00

Please help me, Having this issue since many days.